# use dyn.load or library.dynam to call a C++ function in an R package

Tags: c++, r, package

I am very new to R. I would like to build an R package which will call a C++ function using .Call().
I have a NAMESPACE file, with

```
useDynLib(mypkg)
```

where mypkg is also the function name of my c++ code.

It works if I use this line at the begining of the mypkg.R file:

```
dyn.load("src/mypkg.so")
```

but I want to use library.dynam instead, so in the zzz.R file, I put

```
.onLoad<-function(libname, pkgname)
 {
 library.dynam("mypkg", pkgname, libname)
 }
```

It gives the error when checking the package:

```
...
Error in .Call("mypkg", PACKAGE = "mypkg") : 
C symbol name "mypkg" not in DLL for package "mypkg".
Error : unable to load R code in package 'mypkg'
...
```

It looks like the *.so file is generated in the wrong place? Why there is not /libs folder generated?

I would like to build the package to be os independent, is there a way to do it with dyn.load?

And this may be a very silly question, where did pkgname and libname get their input from?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at one of the many existing packages (with compiled source code) on [CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org).

Smaller and simpler is easier to grok, so you could *e.g.* look at [digest](http://cran.r-project.org/package=digest) which uses a NAMESPACE to load the one shared library built from the handful of C source files, and uses `.Call()` to access the main entry point.

And then there is of course the manual...

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I had test digest, and it works. It generated the /libs folder and put digest.so into it but mine package does not put anything in the /libs folder. The only difference I can see between my code and digest is that I have a Makevars in the /src, should I put something in Makevars to say i want the .so to be save in /libs?

Comment: If you have no external dependencies then you do not need `src/Makevars` as digest proves.

Comment: Your Makevars could be a two-liner adding PKG_CXXFLAGS and PKG_LIBS.

Comment: Yes, that is what I have now. Is there any where else need to be set? Thanks a lot.

Comment: No, that should work. See the manual, or the 900+ other packages on CRAN having a src/ directory.  With the sparse information you provided here, I cannot help you any more.